# Identifying a SMD component?

Tags: integrated-circuit, surface-mount, display

anyone has seen the component in picture?
I have searched google but no results.

[image: IC from a transmitter board, some ports of the IC are connected to display port pins, one to ground and one to power]

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context. Like you I have no idea what the code means but knowing the application might help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ESD protection diode array, probably PRTR5V0U4D. Here's datasheet: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PRTR5V0U4D.pdf
(Datasheet says the marking is "4D").

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is an HDMI connection.  The serial pairs can be plainly seen and line up with the HDMI pinout:

```
Pin     Signal  Description
1   TMDS Data2+      
2   TMDS Data2 Shield    
3   TMDS Data2-      
4   TMDS Data1+      
5   TMDS Data1 Shield    
6   TMDS Data1-      
7   TMDS Data0+      
8   TMDS Data0 Shield    
9   TMDS Data0-      
10  TMDS Clock+      
11  TMDS Clock Shield    
12  TMDS Clock-      
13  CEC      control
14  Reserved/HEC Data−  N.C. on device
15  SCL      DDC clock
16  SDA      DDC data
17  DDC/HEC/CEC Ground   
18  +5 V Power   power EDID/DDC
19  Hot Plug Detect/HEC Data+
```

It follows that the chip in question is some sort of serial device.  Perhaps an EEPROM situated and programmed to provide information about this HDMI device.

As you provided no context these are mostly guesses.  But an obvious choice would be to say this is a monitor's board and the EEPROM is providing information to the host as to the particulars of the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

No idea what it is, but it looks like you can buy them [here](https://m.aliexpress.com/s/item/32269060755.html?trace=wwwdetail2mobilesitedetail&productId=32269060755&productSubject=Marking-code-4D-IC-SOT143&spm=2114.search0305.3.136.mHevAQ&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0_10051_10050_10130_10053_10052_10338_10536_10538_10537_10539_10055_10099_10054_10178_10056_10059_10534_10533_10060_100031_10107_10307_10341_10065_10142_10340_10068_10343_10342_10540_10103_10345_10102_10344_10073_10152_10151_10110_10154_10079_10112_10078_10111_10155_10114_10312_10113_10314_10313_10080_10082_10081_10084_10083_10325_10324,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=11eb8c47-aff3-4c6e-8beb-992810d47fa0&algo_expid=11eb8c47-aff3-4c6e-8beb-992810d47fa0-19).
They appear to have 998 left (as of now)
[image: sot143]

Answer (score 0):

That does look like HDMI, but a few things don't quite make sense.  Its got 20 pins rather than 19.  The last one must be shield.  This must be a bottom view.

Its only connected to the SCL line (and the ground), which doesn't make much sense.  The DDC SDA line looks unhooked, but may be via'd under the connector pads.

A quick search doesn't turn up any I2C EEPROMS in a 6-pin package.

The part markings are unlikely to be searchable.  Its just enough to differentiate it from the manufacturers parts in the same package.  Perhaps thats a logo at the end.

One other possibility is that it's a transient suppressor or clamp.

Comment: SOT23-6 I2C EEPROMs definitely exist

Comment: Aha.   I wasn't doing that right.   I found Microchip and Atmel parts in that package, but they both have SCL/SDA on pins 1 &3, with ground on two.   That doesn't quite match up with whats going on in the picture.